# `delete[]` on `int*` allocated with `new` gives malloc error

Tags: c++

Following my understanding of C++ convention, I have:

```
class BlockRepresentation : public FPRepresentation
{
    private:
        class Block
        {
            public:
                int id;
                int fpDimensions;
                int* position;        // pointers in question
                int* blockDimensions; // pointers in question

                ~Block();
        };
        std::vector<Block> all_blocks;

    public:
        BlockRepresentation( int count, int dimensions, int volumn[] );
        void AddBlock( int id, int position[], int dimensions[] );
        std::string ToGPL();
};
```

where new blocks are created in `AddBlock`:

```
void BlockRepresentation::AddBlock( int id, int position[], 
        int dimensions[] )
{
    Block newBlock;

    newBlock.id = id;
    newBlock.fpDimensions = fpDimensions;
    newBlock.position = new int[fpDimensions];        // pointers in question
    newBlock.blockDimensions = new int[fpDimensions]; // pointers in question

    for (int i = 0; i < fpDimensions; ++i)
    {
        newBlock.position[i] = position[i];
        newBlock.blockDimensions[i] = dimensions[i];
    }

    all_blocks.push_back( newBlock );
}
```

so I have the following destructor:

```
BlockRepresentation::Block::~Block()
{
    delete[] position;
    delete[] blockDimensions;
}
```

but then I get:

```
rep_tests(11039,0x7fff71390000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe4fad00240: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Why should I not `delete[]` the 2 pointers here?

Comment: You're missing a copy constructor to satisfy the [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). My guess is that the pointer isn't allocated because a copy's destructor `delete[]`ed it.

Comment: Interesting, sounds very reasonable from how my tests are using the objects, experimenting now and will get back with the result.

Comment: And for future reference, what do I do to make this a better question? I don't think deleting it on accounts of the downvotes is the best action?

Comment: @Cescante May I ask why you're not using `std::vector<int>` for all your "dynamic arrays"?  You're using it already, so why are you are not using it instead of `int *`?  If you did that, then all of these issues go away.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought I'd use a plain array because these blocks are created to keep track of blocks of arbitrary dimensions for input and output purposes. There are no complicated operations to take advantage of all the other features of vector.

But now that I'm learning more about c++, the better designs may be:

1. use 2 vector<int[]> to keep track of the positions and volumes separately and get rid of the Block inner class -OR- 2. use vectors everywhere as you suggested.

Comment: @Cescante The goal is to get the code to work first.  By introducing pointers into your class, you're now responsible to make sure that the class has the correct copy semantics since instances are being placed in a vector, and your class lacks these characteristics because of the raw pointer usage.  Instead you could have done something [like this](http://ideone.com/VvDbDh) and have the code working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you violated the rule of three, and the violation is very obvious:

```
{
    Block newBlock;

    // snip

    all_blocks.push_back( newBlock );
}
```

When this function returns, the `newBlock` object goes out of scope, and its destructor will delete all the `new`ed arrays.

But you `push_back`()ed this object. This constructs a copy of the object into the vector. Because your `Block` does not define a copy constructor, the default copy-constructor simply makes a copy of all the pointers to the `new`ed arrays.

If you somehow manage to avoid dereferencing the no-longer valid pointers, or you survived that experience, you're not of the woods yet. That's because, when the vector gets destroyed, and its `Block`s get destroyed, their destructors will, once again, attempt to `delete` the same `new`ed arrays that were already `delete`d once before.

Instant crash.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your `Block` destructor.  It is doing its job, which is releasing the memory that is pointed to by your two `int *` member variables.  The problem is that the destructor is being called on the same pointer value multiple times, which results in a double-free error.

The entity that causes this is the `std::vector<Block>`, since a `std::vector` will make copies of your `Block` object, and your `Block` object is not safely copyable.

Since the member variables of `Block` that are pointers are `position` and `blockDimensions`, the most painless way to alleviate this issue is to use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int *`, as demonstrated by [this sample program](http://ideone.com/VvDbDh).

However, if you really wanted to use `int *`, you would need to implement a user-defined copy constructor.  In addition, a user-defined assignment operator would complement the copy constructor.  This is what is called the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

```
 #include <algorithm>
 //...
 class Block
 {
    public:
       int id;
       int fpDimensions;
       int *position;
       int *blockDimensions;

       Block() : position(nullptr), blockDimensions(nullptr),
                 id(0), fpDimensions(0) {}
      ~Block()
      {
          delete [] position;
          delete [] blockDimensions;
      }

      Block(const Block& rhs) : id(rhs.id), fpDimensions(rhs.fpDimensions),
                                position(new int[rhs.fpDimensions]),
                                blockDimensions(new int[rhs.fpDimensions])
      {
         std::copy(rhs.position, rhs.position + fpDimensions, position);
         std::copy(rhs.blockDimensions, rhs.blockDimensions + fpDimensions,
                   blockDimensions);
      }

      Block& operator=(const Block& rhs)
      {
         Block temp(rhs);
         std::swap(temp.position, position);
         std::swap(temp.blockDimensions, blockDimensions);
         std::swap(temp.id, id);
         std::swap(temp.fpDimensions, fpDimensions);
         return *this;
      }
  };
```

See the live sample [here](http://ideone.com/ukD6L7).

See all of the hoops we had to jump through to get the `Block` class to behave correctly when used within a `std::vector`, as opposed to simply using `std::vector<int>`?